# Тип редактора tinymce

Tags: drupal

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Есть drupal6 + wysiwyg + tinymce. На сайте все поля типа textarea выводятся в виде миниредактора. Мне хотелось бы на одной определенной страничке выводить textarea в обычном виде (без кнопок редактора, переключателя full html и т.п.)

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того, какая именно версия у tinymce. Я использовал jQuery package. Но принцип думаю одинаковый.

Открываем файл tiny_mce.js
Ищем init

```
tinyMCE.init({
```

Меняем mode с textareas на specific_textareas, и добавляем параметр editor_deselector: nowysiwyg

В итоге должно получиться так

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_deselector: "nowysiwyg",
```

Теперь textarea с классом nowysiwyg не будут преобразовываться в wysiwyg

Comment: спасибо. а не сталкивались с такой проблемой, когда после деминификации кода файла tiny_mce.js редактор отключается на всех страницах? после этого вводить код, предложенный вами не имеет смысла

Comment: Скиньте примеры html textarea, когда работает и не работает. Попробуем вместе разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю этот код надо вводить на нужной странице в тэгах:

```
<script></script>
```

а не лезть в файл редактора напрямую.